# Как передать класс и интерфейс в другой метод

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с этой проблемой и не могу найти решение. Попробую обрисовать, то, что я хочу реализовать.

```
// Мои интерфейс
public interface IModel
{
    Dictionary<string, string> toArray(MySqlDataReader reader);

    IModel New(Dictionary<string, string> data);
}

// Сюда я хочу передать интерфейс и класс
// Класс заранее не известен, известно лишь какой интерфейс он использует
// Интерфейс мне нужен для вызова методов этого класса, который не определен
public List<T> Select<T>(IModel model, string query)
{
    List<T> response = null;

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<T> results = null;

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            results = new List<T>();
        }

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = null;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data = model.toArray(reader);
                results.Add(model.New(data));
            }

            reader.NextResult();
        }

        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return response;
    }
}

// Тут я пытаюсь передать интерфейс и параметры
public List<Ticker> All()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tickers";

    List<Ticker> tickers = App.MySQL.Select<Ticker>(Ticker, query);

    return tickers;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить такую задачу)

Comment: where T: IMyInterface - see [msdn intro to generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обьявление generic метода:

```
public List<T> Select<T>(T model, string query)
    where T: ITicker
{
    model.Foo(string.Empty);
}

public class Ticker : ITicker
{
    public void Foo(string bar)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface ITicker
{
    void Foo(string bar);
}
```

Внутри метода можно будет вызывать у model методы интерфейса T.

Использование:

```
List<Ticker> tickers = App.MySQL.Select<Ticker>(new Ticker(), query);
```

Подробнее в документации:

- [MSDN - An Introduction to C# Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

ЗЫ Смотрю на ваш код и пытаюсь понять, зачем вам в метод передавать экземпляр если внутри он используется с одной целью - чтобы вызвать .ToArray определённый в IModel.

ЗЗЫ Кажется вы пытаетесь изобрести аналог [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Если с учебной целью - ок, но если для работы - то можете просто готовую библиотеку подключить. Уверен - понравится.

Comment: А как тогда мне вызвать методы не определенного класса?

Comment: @СтасЧурилов Ожидаемый вопрос. Вы же не написали, что именно делает ваш метод `toArray` и `New` - так что вариантов несколько. Самый очевидный - в том же классе, где `All` сделать private метод. Покажите код, который вы хотите вызвать, может там и не нужны будут никакие обобщения. А для `New` я не уверен, что вы хотите именно такую сигнатуру использовать, там напрашивается фабрика которая new T2 вернёт.

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Я на шарпе дня 4 всего. Учусь и делаю, делаю и учусь)

Comment: public Ticker New(Dictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            Ticker ticker = new Ticker();

            ticker.id = Convert.ToInt16(data["id"]);
            .....
            return ticker;
        }

Comment: public Dictionary<string, string> toArray(MySqlDataReader reader)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            data.Add("id", reader["id"].ToString());
            ....

            return data;
        }